# MySQL: Use REGEX to extract all matches from one records

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I try to extract all tag in string and add them to new columns in mysql
for example :

```
string :

hello #name# , current time is : #time# and today is : #today_date#

output :

#name#
#time#
#today_date#
```

I want to search all rows for a `text` columns in a table and update `tags_list` columns with output result

for find all rows with tags we can use from this query

```
SELECT `text` FROM 'table' WHERE `text` REGEXP '#.*#'
```

but how can i extract all marches and update `tags_list` columns with output result ?

Comment: Few questions: 1/. Are the tag optional? Could you have the same message but without the time for exemple? 2/. Is the Text format mandatory? An json, Xml or anthing that is design to be parse. 3/. How mutch do you fear SQL Injection? 4/. If table, column and value are in the message why it's not directly a SQL query?

Comment: how should resulting values be distributed across `tag_list` column?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That's is not important , tag_list only for show to admin to know about tags and which tags can use for that text

Comment: @DragandDrop 1- Yes , 2 - Yes , 4 -  text is just a message and tags replaced with a correct value ( for each message different )

Comment: I think you are looking for Lookahead and Lookbehind

Comment: Is this close to your requirment ? https://regex101.com/r/R7pMIR/1

Comment: @DragandDrop i don't have any problem with regex pattern ! this pattern work correctly : '#.*?#' my problem is : how to extract all value from string in mysql\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE tags_list varchar(2000) ;
  DECLARE tags varchar(800) ;

  SET @start_loc := 1;
  SET @start_pos := -1;
  SET @end_pos := -1;

  SET @total_len =  LENGTH(str);

  WHILE @start_loc < @total_len
  DO

    SET @start_pos := LOCATE('#',str,@start_loc);
    SET @end_pos := LOCATE('#',str,@start_pos+1 );


    IF @start_pos > 1 AND @end_pos > 0 THEN
      SET @len = @end_pos - @start_pos + 1;


      SET tags := SUBSTRING(str, @start_pos, @len);
    IF  tags_list IS NULL THEN
        SET tags_list :=  tags;
    ELSE
      set tags_list  := CONCAT_WS("
", tags_list, tags);
    END IF;
        SET @start_loc := @end_pos+1;
    ELSE
      SET @start_loc := @total_len+1;
    END IF;

  END WHILE;


  IF  tags_list IS NULL THEN
        SET tags_list :=  '';
  END IF;

  RETURN tags_list;
END
```

and then for update columns

```
UPDATE `table` SET `tags_list`= func_name(`text`)
```

maybe useful for someone ...